# Query Nearest locations within 10 miles from AWS DynamoDB in Java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-dynamodb, geohashing

I am new to AWS DynamoDB and I want to find the list of locations within r mile of radius from DynamoDB table( based on Latitude, Longitude and GeoHash)
What is the best possible way to achieve this?

Comment: You may try to have a look at the DynamoDb GeoLibrary  https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-geo-library-for-dynamodb/

Comment: Could you share what you have tried so far? [ask]

Comment: @HoRn - I have followed the link  https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/geohash.html and calculated the 9 geohash boundaries. I can scan with these value but not query and scan is a costly operation. Is there a way to query DynamoDB(what should be the partition key and sort key - Table holds lat, lon, geoHash)

Answer (score 0):

This is something that, unless you are working with a very small data set, Dyanmo is not really suited for.

What you need is a weighted directional graph that links all points to all others. This kind of multi linkage is not what dynamo is good at. You would need, in effect, to have a dynamo that is set up like this:

```
pk: a location identifier | sk: another location id-number of miles from pk
```

then you can do a single query against a given location identifier with all values that are less than miles away, and you would get your answer.

you'd also have to query the *exact* point you want to know what is nearby, and youd have to have that *eaxact* point in the db. No doing 'close to this point' queries.

But as soon as you start dealing with thousands of data points you might see a problem. Even one of those locations will have to have *every other location as an sk under the same pk* in order to do that query. So you'd end up with:

```
pk           | sk
location 1   | location2#miles
location 1   | location3#miles
location 1   | location4#miles
location 2   | location1#miles
location 2   | location3#miles
location 2   | location4#miles
location 3   | location1#miles... ect
```

This is what a directed weighted graph object structure is for - and that object structure that actually does translate very well to dynamodb... (because under the fancy hood a directed weighted graph object is just a series of attributes saying how far away a given other object is) but may be impractical depending on how granular you are trying to be.

Comment: Hi lynkfox, this solution seems to be perfect for small data set. I am looking for a solution that's feasible with thousands of locations.

Comment: yes indeed... but no matter what solution you end up using, it is going to look much the same way. A Weighted Graph object, each node (ie: location) will have to have all connecting nodes in its attributes. This is how things like Maps and navmesh grids work - and so its entirely possible with billions of locations, but yes - it is very memory intensive.

Comment: I am stuck here, did you find a way ?